# AddEventListner to created tag

Tags: javascript

im trying to add an eventlistner to this html tag that i am creating with a api call

```
    handleProducts()

    function handleProducts() {

        var display = document.getElementById("display")

        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/"

        fetch(url)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(function (data) {
                console.log(data)

                var products = data

                for (var i in products) {

                    var product = `
                        <div class="col-lg-4">
                            <img class="thumbnail" src="${products[i].img}" alt="">
                                <div class="box-element product">
                                    <h6><strong>${products[i].title}</strong></h6>
                                    <hr>
                                    <button data-product=${products[i].id} data-action = "add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
                                    <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="">View</a>
                                    <h4 class="price">${products[i].price}</h4>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        `
                    display.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', product)    
                    
                    
                }
                
            })


            
    }

    function handleAddToCart(){

        var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("update-cart")
        console.log(updateBtns)

        for (var y = 0; y < updateBtns.length; y++) {

            updateBtns[y].addEventListener("click", function () {

                console.log("Clicked")

            })

        }

    }

   handleAddToCart()
```

Ive included all the code because mabye there is something else i need to add when adding an eventlistner to this type of html code. The problem is that this does not console log clicked when i click the button. Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: i found out you just have to call the function inside the first function. After i did that it worked, but thanks for trying to help, appretate it! <3

Answer (score 0):

You are calling both functions at the same time, and the fetch is not complete yet while you try to add the event listener. You can move the function call handleAddToCart() inside the first function after you create that element.

Comment: thats what i thought to, but the when i console log the buttons its displays all three buttons that are created. Tried putting the function inside handleProducts but it still doesnt work.... and i dont know what to search for to debug this.